# Underscore.php throwing Non-static method __::invoke() should not be called statically

Tags: php, underscore.php

I've just upgraded to PHP 5.5.3 and I noticed that Underscore.php is throwing an odd error:

```
Non-static method __::invoke() should not be called statically
```

The code in question that's causing this error look like this:

```
$params = \__::invoke( $params, function( $value ) {
   ...
} );
```

Plowing through the Underscore.php source, I don't understand why this error is being thrown since the call to `invoke` should be handled by the `__callStatic` handler:

```
public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
  $mixins =& self::getInstance()->_mixins;
  return call_user_func_array($mixins[$name], $arguments);
}
```

I don't want to mess with the error reporting settings in PHP because this would mean making a PHP settings change through the entire stack.

My current workaround is:

```
$__ = new \__();

$params = $__->invoke( $params, function( $value ) {
  ...
} );
```

Which is clumsy to say the least. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're getting an `E_STRICT` error, and it looks like this has been an issue for quite some time:

https://github.com/brianhaveri/Underscore.php/issues/4

Underscore.php hasn't been updated in a few years, so I wouldn't hold your breath that they are going to fix this anytime soon.

`E_STRICT` only became part of `E_ALL` as of PHP 5.4. That would explain why it's been appearing only since your upgrade.

**Update**: Take a look at this fork of Underscore.php, it has fixed these PHP 5.4+ errors:

https://github.com/JonathanAquino/Underscore.php

Answer (score 0):

> Plowing through the Underscore.php source, I don't understand why this error is being thrown since the call to invoke should be handled by the __callStatic handler:

That's a misunderstanding of how PHP works. The `__call` and `__callStatic` are only triggered when the function is not accessible (private or non-existent). In this case, the `invoke` function does exist, so PHP calls that. Before traits were introduced, mixing non-static and static function calls was an "accepted" way of doing "mixins."

Example:

```
<?php
class A
{
  public function __call($name, $args)
  {
    echo "__call $name\n";
  }

  static public function __callStatic($name, $args)
  {
    echo "__callStatic $name\n";
  }

  public function foo()
  {
    echo "foo()\n";
  }
}

A::foo();
```

You'll see that the defined `foo()` method is called.

This is just a case where the library needs to be updated to conform with PHP's evolving standards. Having a method act as both a static and non-static method is simply poor practice and PHP is finally calling out people for doing that.

Slightly off-topic, but it's also worth noting that `__call` always has precedence over `__callStatic` when a method is invoked from inside the context of the object. e.g., In this example, the `__call` method is used for `A::bar()` due to it being ambiguous.

```
class A
{
   public function test()
   {
     A::bar();
   }

   public function __call($name, $args) {}
   static public function __callStatic($name, $args) {}
}
```

Comment: Not to sure what the point of your answer is. The `invoke` method does exists, just not as static. So calling `__::invoke` will trigger `__callStatic` which will call `invoke` on an instance of `__`, I got that, thanks.

Comment: `__callStatic` is *not* called. Read my answer and run my first example. :)